# I want to perform a multiplication with add in assembler that uses a loop

Tags: assembly

This is code for [ZEP2](http://hoadd.noordhoff.nl/sites/7094/7094-webpage1-2.htm), a simple ISA for teaching.

```
##

begin   load R1, 0
        load R2, 7

loop    add R1, y
        dec R2
        store R1, (0x0010)
        cmp R2, 0
        jeq stop 
        jmp loop

stop    halt

y dat 16

##
```

This is my code so far. I want to multiply 7 with 16.

I need to load 0 in register then I need to have x = 7 and y = 16. Than add y to 0 and distract 1 from x until I have 0 for x and 112 for the R1. So this loop has to go for 7 runs and each time add 16 to the previous number that is stored.

Comment: Ok, so what is your question?  What's stopping you from doing that?  And why are you storing to memory instead of just using registers?  Also, what ISA is this?  Is it MSP430 by any chance?  It's not x86, but you probably still need an operand for `dec`.

Comment: I use ZEP2 simulator.  R1 = 0 and R2 = 16 . I need to compare the 7 to 0. How can I use 7. the 7 needs to be the x in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to multiply without using the MUL instruction.

You need an three variables, an accumulator, the multiplier and the multiplicand.  One of the latter two will be decremented down to zero, while the other stays constant and will be repeatedly summed into the accumulator.

You want the C equivalent of:

```
int m1 = 7;
int m2 = 16;

int acc = 0;
while ( m1 > 0 ) {
   acc += m2;
   m1--;
}
```

In ZEP2, one of those three variables needs to be in memory, since this machine only has 2 registers.

You have a somewhat right idea, but are mixing up these three variables.

I'd suggest using R1 for the accumulator (the answer), R2 for the m1 (starts at 7), and memory 0x010 (as you've chosen) for the multiplier (m2, set to 16).

That means that
    `acc += m2;` translates to `add R1, (0x010)`, for example, and,
    `m1--;` translates to `dec R2`.

The `cmp` might look like `cmp R2, 0`; however, let's note that the `dec` sets the condition codes, so we don't need to compare to zero in order to use a conditional branch.

---

To use `x dat 7`, then before the loop change `m1 = 7;`, to `m1 = x;` (C code), which would be a `load r1, (x)` instruction with the ()'s to get the value of x not the address of x, I believe.

Similar with `y dat 16` change `m2 = 16;` to `m2 = y;` — but with this one as `m2` is in memory we need to move it there with two instructions: one to load it into a register and one to store it into 0x0010 as in: `load r2, (y); store r2, (0x0010)`.  (Here we're using R2 just as a short-lived temporary, so do this before `int acc = 0;`, since that also uses R2...)

Comment: I edited the code. It works. What is the range it can calculate? The only issue I have is if I make a 'x dat 7' and fill it in the R2 it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have to say much, but here is my ARM program.
I hope you will find it helpful ( Made by Miku ) :

```
    MOV R2, #3        //R2 is first number. Set 2nd operand manually for calculations
    MOV R3, #2        // R3 is second number. Set 2nd operand manually for calculations.
    MOV R4, #0        // Initializes R4, which is the sum of R2 x R3.

    CMP R3, #0        // Checks if multiplying by 0.
    BEQ Stop

Again: ADD R4, R4, R2   // First instance of multiplication
    SUBS R3, R3, #1   // So count decreases by one.
    CMP R3, #0        // Checks if count has reached 0
    BNE Again         // If count isn't 0, go back to Again label.

Stop: HLT               //Program ended. Look at R4 for the answer.
```